# Open Android games(.apk) using a master app(.apk)

Tags: android, eclipse

How to open a installed game not from main menu, but from another app (say master app).
I've created Android games using AIR 3.2 for Android in Adobe Flash Professional CS6 and installed around 50 games on my Android device and all the games are there on the main menu. First step I want to do is that:
When I install the game, I want to hidden the installed games from the main menu, so that the users should not be able to play my games simply from main menu.
Now I want to created another app (say master app) with only the games Images and its names inside this app(the games which I created and installed) and arrange it in rows and column based on some categories.
now I want to link this game images with their respective games which is already installed in the device, so that when the user tap on this game image, the actual game should open and the user should be able to play the game.
Can anyone please help me out to achive this goal...
please post your comments and sample codes which will help me to develope this app.

Answer (score 2):

To do something like this you can :

- Remove the games from the launcher (i.e. the "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" intent-filters in each manifest.xml)
- Start your games from your main app by using intents